# get garbled character when i turn pandas into pyspark dataframe,in python2.7

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, decode

origin pandas dataframe is below:

```
       id           song_name
001MpsbI1FoQgs02 只想好好爱一回
000qq4Kk2WMPgU02  大森林的早晨
```

and I try to convert pandas dataframe into pyspark dataframe.

code:

```
all_song_py=spark.createDataFrame(all_song[[u'id',u'song_name']],mySchema)
```

the result is:

```
|     id         |    song_name         

|001MpsbI1FoQgs02|åªæƒ³å¥½å¥½çˆ±ä¸€å›ž           
|000qq4Kk2WMPgU02|å¤§æ£®æž—çš„æ—©æ™¨
```

I tried to decode the garbled character using below code,but it doesn't work.

```
decode_udf= udf(lambda val: urllib.unquote(val.encode('utf-8')).decode('gb18030'), StringType())
```

the result is :

```
氓聫陋忙聝鲁氓楼陆氓楼陆莽聢卤盲赂聙氓聸聻
```

any solution?

Comment: what is `mySchema`? And how did you print out the dataframe? using `.show()`?

Comment: mySchema is string format schema.and yes,i'm using .show() function to print them out.

Answer (score 1):

solved!
by import pyspark.sql.functions encode and decode function.